# json stringify failing when value is without double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, regex

When I try to convert below json to string, getting unexpected desired output when the value is not surrounded with double quotes:

**JSON data:**

```
[
{
    "Name": "param1",
    "Type": "Integer",
    "Default Value": 8778
},
{
    "Name": "param2",
    "Type": "Float",
    "Default Value": 1.4
},
{
    "Name": "param3",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default Value": true
},
{
    "Name": "param4",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default Value": "test"
}
]
```

**Current result:**

```
[{"Name":"param1","Type":"Integer","Default Value":8778},  {"Name":"param2","Type":"Float","Default Value":**1.4**}, {"Name":"param3","Type":"String","Default Value":**true**}, {"Name":"param4","Type":"String","Default Value":**"test"**}]
```

**Expected result:**

```
[{"Name":"param1","Type":"Integer","Default Value":**"8778"**},  {"Name":"param2","Type":"Float","Default Value":**"1.4"**}, {"Name":"param3","Type":"String","Default Value":**"true"**}, {"Name":"param4","Type":"String","Default Value":**"test"**}]
```

I tried below code: but it is not working.

```
  jsondata = JSON.stringify(confTableData);          
  jsondata = jsondata.replace(/:(\d+|\d*\.\d+)([,\}])/g, ':"$1"$2'); // only Integer & Float type values replaced         
  jsondata = jsondata.replace(/:(.)([,\}])/g, ':"$1"$2'); It gives strange result.
```

Can anyone help me on the regex pattern to match my requirement.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, JSON doesn't need quotes around numbers, and it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do ?

Comment: why would you expect the number to be changed to a string?

Comment: Perhaps, you need to allow spaces in the first and second regexps? Also, you can match integer and float numbers with just `-?\d*\.?\d+`.

Comment: If you want to change the number to string, simply quotes around integer and float. But I don't know what you expect exactly.

Comment: Do not manipulate JSON strings with regexp. Also, consider changing the question title. I guess you mean "JSON.stringify: convert numbers and booleans to strings".

Comment: I want to convert this json to xml. when I try to do, since number and boolean values does not have quote, it is generating xml file incorrectly..

Comment: Perhaps you could fix your JSON-to-XML converter to handle non-strings as values. After all, it's very common for JSON to contain non-string values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON spec outlines what you're seeing as standard behavior and I'd recommend that you operate on the number as a number instead of a string.

If you need to modify this for some reason, you can use a "replacer" function as shown in the [JSON.stringify spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
var numbersAsStringsJSON = JSON.stringify(myData, replacer);

function replacer(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "number") { return String(value); }
  else { return value; }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17b8x4mb/) for working example.

Comment: I guess you should also convert booleans to strings.

Comment: you are great man. I was trying with regex to find the pattern.. this simplified my half-day work.. :)

Comment: yes, you could convert any of the data passed through, or drop values etc.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers do not need to be wrapped in double quotes. Check out some of the examples on [json.org](http://json.org/example.html).

If you want the numbers to be strings in JSON, you can make them strings before you stringify your object, e.g.:

```
var data = {
  "Name": "param1",
  "Type": "Integer",
  "Default Value": 8778
};
data["Default Value"] = String(data["Default Value"]);

var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

If you do it before you stringify the JSON you won't need to run a regex over it.